# How can state stored in a python descriptor object be accessed outside the descriptor?

Tags: python

Is it possible to get at state stored in a python descriptor?

For example:

```
class Price(object):
    def __init__(self, dollars):
        self.dollars = dollars

    class Convert(object):
        def __init__(self, rate):
            self.rate = rate
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            return instance.dollars * self.rate
    euros = Convert(0.75)

p = Price(20.0)

print p.dollars
print p.euros
```

works as expected; however, I'd like to get at the `rate` that is stored within the `Convert` descriptor that is managing `p.euros` is that possible? Clearly `p.euros.rate` won't work but I'm not sure how to get at the euros instance of Converter.

(I realize that in this simplified case making euros a property and putting rate on price makes sense it was just a simple example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access the descriptor through the class, the `instance` argument of `__get__` will be None. You can check for that and return the descriptor itself:

```
class Price(object):
    def __init__(self, dollars):
        self.dollars = dollars

    class Convert(object):
        def __init__(self, rate):
            self.rate = rate

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            if instance is None:
                # Accessed through class, return the descriptor instead.
                return self
            return instance.dollars * self.rate

    euros = Convert(0.75)
```

Then you get the rate like this:

```
>>> Price.euros.rate
0.75
```

Comment: Any ideas about how to get at it without making assumptions about the implementation of the descriptor?

Comment: @Finn `Price.__dict__['euros'].rate` but this is hacky. You should really fix your descriptor if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Actually @yak's comment on his own answer above gives the right way to do it: using the class `__dict__`  attribute.

Therefore, you can get the descriptor by doing, (on your code, which lists `p` as an instance of `Price`) by doing:
`p.__class__.__dict__["euros"]`

Note however that the descriptor itself is a "class variable" - so, still on your example, if you need different "Price" objects to have different "rate" attributes on the "euro" attribute, the Convert descriptor has to keep the "rate" not as self.rate, but in some (possibly name mangled) attribute of the "instance" parameter passed to the "__get__" and "__set__" methods.

If that is the case, you could access that attribute directly on the instance itself - or implement some "get" and "setters" (or a nested property) for dealing with the descirptor attribute you want to manipulate in the descriptor's class itself.

Comment: Accessing `__dict__` will do the job but it's unpythonic and it's not how the descriptors were meant to be used. Just sayin'

Comment: Assessing `__dict__`is the only way of getting a descriptor object, and it is not an  implementation detail - it is on the language specification that the retrieval of object and class attributes works like this. Therefore, there is nothing "unpythonic"  about it.